# How to take values from different classes in diamond-inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    protected:
        std::string _name;
        int _points;
        int _energy;
    
    public:

        A(std::string name, int points, int energy) : _name(name), _points(points), _energy(energy)
        {            
        }
        A(std::string name) : _name(name), _points(10), _energy(10)
        {
        }
};

class B : public virtual A
{
    public:

        B(std::string name): A(name, 20, 20)
        {
        }
};

class C : public virtual A
{
    public:

        C(std::string name) : A(name, 30, 30)
        {
        }
};

class D : public B, public C
{
    private:

            std::string _name_d;

    public:

        D(std::string name): A(name), B(name), C(name), _name_d(name)
        {
            A::_name = "another name";
            _points = B::_points;
            _energy = C::_energy;
            std::cout << "name class D   " << _name_d << std::endl;
            std::cout << "name class A   " << A::_name << std::endl;
            std::cout << "energy class D " << _energy << std::endl;
            std::cout << "points class D " << _points << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    D d("Bill");
    return (0);
}
```

This is my first Diamond-inheritance code. On the class C I need to take value of _points from class B and value of _energy from class C, but output is next:

```
name class D   Bill
name class A   another name
energy class D 10
points class D 10
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to be using virtual inheritance, then, if you want the `B` and `C` subobjects of a `D` instance to have distinct underlying `A` subsubobjects.

Comment: Usually one should avoid multiple inheritance and even more with diamond inheritance or virtual inheritance... It can make the code harder to maintain. In fact, many languages does not support multiple inheritance (or only for interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to notice is that, not matter which prefix you use, the members variables are all the same object. And with this I mean the following:

1. `A::_name` is the same as `B::_name` and  `C::_name` and `D::_name`
2. `A::_points` is the same as `B::_points` and  `C::_points` and `D::_points`
3. etc.

The first constructor being called is the one from the virtual base class, then the intermediate classes and, finally, the derived class.

**Intermediate classes have no effect in the construction of the base class.**

So the output you've got is perfectly fine: The field `_name_d` belongs only to class `D` but the other three are available in the four classes because they are declared in the base virtual class.

If you intended to have `B::_points = 20` and `C::_points = 30` then you'll have to create more objects because any object of type `D` will set them to `10`.

Again: You have only one object, and only one `_name` and `_points` and `_energy`.